# want to create multiple dropzones using dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

i am making a **comparison app** which have two different drag & drop areas. each one should act like a single drop zone (to replace or remove each image).

issue:

```
var previewaDropzone = new Dropzone("div#previewa",{url:'/url1.json'});
var previewbDropzone = new Dropzone("div#previewb",{url:'/url2.json'});
```

but dropzone throw exception

> Dropzone already attached.

Note: *i cant use templates of dropzone.js because both areas are on different places*

any way to achieve given above functionality using Dropzone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Dropzone FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#i-get-the-error-dropzone-already-attached-when-creating-the-dropzone)

> I get the error "Dropzone already attached." when creating the
>   Dropzone.
>
> This is most likely due to the autoDiscover feature of Dropzone.
>
> When Dropzone starts, it scans the whole document, and looks for
>   elements with the dropzone class. It then creates an instance of
>   Dropzone for every element found. If you, later on, create a Dropzone
>   instance yourself, you'll create a second Dropzone which causes this
>   error.
>
> So you can either:
>
> ```
> Turn off autoDiscover globally like this: Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;, or
> Turn off autoDiscover of specific elements like this: Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;
>
> You don't have to create an instance of Dropzone programmatically in most situations! It's recommended to leave autoDiscover enabled,
> ```
>
> and configure your Dropzone in the init option of your configuration.

Further down the FAQ you can see an example of the `init()` function which you can use like this:

```
<script>
  // previewa is the configuration for the element that has an id attribute
  // with the value previewa
  Dropzone.options.previewa = {
    init: function() {
      Dropzone.options.previewaDropzone = false;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: i have read this faq. actually i am having trouble in [** configure your Dropzone in the init option of your configuration.**] part. how to configure two different divs to act like different dropzones.

Comment: I tried to adapt a code example from a different section of the FAQ to work for you, but I haven't tested this (Dropzone is a little tricky to test on JSFiddle)

Comment: i just tried it but but issue still there while creating another dropzone. after disabling first one. according to your given code!

Comment: Sorry the first one was an example, you would have to do that with both, but I didn't want to present a final solution until I had worked out a way to reproduce and test your question and my suggested answer.  Maybe a cleaner approach would be to disable it globally.

Comment: It worked for thanks ..... it did according to your code and found bug  which was id mismatch in dropzone instance and div.

Answer (score 6):

Oof made it! I'll leave this here in case someone needs it.

Let's say that you have your dropzones like these:

```
<div class="dropzone js-dropzone-upload "></div>
<div class="dropzone js-dropzone-upload "></div>
```

Define a class for each dropzone, call them whatever you want. In this case they are called js-dropzone-upload.

Iterate over them, through a forEach and then pass the "element" parameter to the constructor of the Dropzone:

```
    <script>
// This prevents Dropzone to autodiscover the elements, 
// allowing you to better control it.
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-dropzone-upload'))
                            .forEach(element => {
                                var myDropzone = new Dropzone(element, {
                                    url: "/Media/AjaxUpload", maxFilesize: 10, addRemoveLinks: true, maxFiles: 1,
//Omit the "headers" in case you don't need it.
                                    headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1]).value }
                                });
                                myDropzone.on("success", function (response) {
                                    document.getElementById('eMediaID').value = response.xhr.response.replace(/\"/g, "");
                                });
                            });

    </script>
```

Bonus: 
I made this with Webpack and TypeScript:

```
 if (document.querySelector('.js-ballot-upload') !== null) {
            require(['../dropzone/dropzone-amd-module.min.js'],
            (Dropzone) => {

                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

                Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-ballot-upload'))
                    .forEach(element => {
                        console.log(element);
                        var myDropzone = new Dropzone(element,
                        {
                            url: "/Media/AjaxUpload",
                            maxFilesize: 10,
                            addRemoveLinks: true,
                            maxFiles: 1,
                            headers: {
                                "__RequestVerificationToken": (<HTMLInputElement>document
                                    .getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1]).value
                            }
                        });
                        myDropzone.on("success",
                            function(response) {
                                (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('eMediaID')).value = response.xhr.response
                                    .replace(/\"/g, "");
                            });
                    });
            });
```